# Правила русской пунктуации

Tags: пунктуация

Первые правила русской пунктуации появились в 1956 году. Интересно, а как до этого люди расставляли знаки препинания? На что они тогда опирались? на логику? здравый смысл? интуицию? А может быть, наши предки понятия не имели, что такое пунктуация? Но это и неважно. Мне интересно знать вот что: почему разработчики правил решили,что между однородными членами предложения, однородными частями БСП нужно ставить запятую, а между взаимообусловленными частями бессоюзного сложного предложения — двоеточие или тире?

Comment: Настолько разрозненные вопросы лучше спрашивать по отдельности.

Comment: Почему, позвольте спросить!

Comment: «А может быть, наши предки понятия не имели, что такое пунктуация? Но это и неважно», — пишете, а потом идёт вопрос. Так «неважное» — а оно и, пардон, легкомысленное, — можно  легко убрать. В этом виде вопрос несъедобен. После правки будет легче сформулировать тему: сейчас она не отработана совсем.

Comment: "На что они тогда опирались? на логику? здравый смысл? интуицию?" Маленькая буква после вопросительного знака у автора - это правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Не "разработчики правил", а те, кто добавил к существующим правилам/рекомендациям  выведенные нормы из классической литературы.

Ответ Розенталя (он также сыграл ключевую роль в составлении правил 1956 года):
- Помню, еще в десятом классе учительница рекомендовала нам готовиться к экзаменационному диктанту по пособию Розенталя. Потом был престижный вуз, семинары по современному русскому языку и снова: Розенталь, Розенталь, Розенталь... Задаешь преподавателю логичный вопрос: "Почему пишется так, а не эдак?" — и получаешь логичный ответ: "А по правилу Розенталя". Неужели до вас писали как Бог на душу положит, без всяких правил?
- Конечно, нет. Правила существовали всегда, еще со времен Ломоносова. Мне же досталась самая черновая работа: отыскать источники, выбрать, добавить, систематизировать, подобрать примеры.

Правила пунктуации основаны на том, как люди говорят (делаются ли в таком случае в речи логические ударения и паузы [и какие паузы и как они влияют на интонацию] или нет), и на структуре (вклинивается ли в предложение что-то "чужеродное", не имеющее грамматического согласования с окружающим или нет).

Однородность — это случай перечисления, самого простого, в нём, соответственно, используется простой знак — запятая, а для взаимообусловленных частей решили использовать что-то другое, так как ситуация другая. Всё логично.

Comment: Запятая появилась в 1520, точка в 1480, пробел в 1400. Пробел, Карл! До 1400-го тексты писались без пробелов!? Эх, лучше бы у нас было как в английском - без запятых почти (только логические запятые типа "казнить нельзя помиловать", что составляет лишь 1% от бестолковой кучи запятых в современном русском. Ну и отдельный знак можно ввести для поэтов, чтобы декламировать паузы).

Comment: Как можно без пробелов? Как тогда слова отделялись? В русском хоть для запятых правил тьма, но мне всё ясно - благодаря Розенталю и логическим ударениям, а в английском такого деятеля не нашлось и некоторые моменты покрыты тайной и информации 0. Например, не удалось найти, соединяет ли там общий элемент простые предложения, между которыми требуется запятая, как в русском.

Comment: Без пробелов глупо, да. Наборы слов отделялись лишь переходом к новой строке.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#:~:text=%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%20%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0.-,%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%20%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5,%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0.

Comment: Большое количество правил пунктуации в русском языке обусловлено свободным порядком слов.

Comment: И то верно, сравнение с английским несколько падает в цене. Можно взглянуть на другие языки:

Comment: Римлян не впечатлило новаторство Аристофана, и поэтому с началом их господства в Средиземноморье предвестники современных знаков препинания снова пропали из манускриптов. Цицерон, один из самых известных римских ораторов, даже говорил, что окончание предложения не должно определяться ни паузой, взятой говорящим, ни каким-либо символом, поставленным переписчиком, а только лишь «требованиями ритма». Позже римляне еще немного поэкспериментировали с разграничением·слов·точками, но тоже без особого энтузиазма — во втором веке нашей эры они были отменены.Культ публичных выступлений был слишком силен

Comment: Но английский, как ни странно, более универсальный, там нет такого, что не звучит, а есть лишь можно или нельзя. Получается, что там полная свобода в выражении мысли. Поэтому и приходится переделывать английские названия фильмов, а порой и вовсе менять.

Comment: Еще есть такая закономерность. В английском на выражение одного и того же предложения требуется больше слов (позиций) в среднем. С другой стороны, в русском слова тоже можно разбить на приставки, корни и суффиксы, и тогда больше позиций будет уже в русском. Таким образом в английском одна система выражения мысли (позиции в предложении), а в русском две системы (позиции в словах и позиции в предложении). И тут можно подумать, что лучше одна мощная система, или две послабее + их согласование?

Comment: Не слышал о такой закономерности. Примеры лучше всего проливают свет (больше читаю примеры Розенталя, чем его правила). Но в английском тоже есть "позиции в словах" (да, их гораздо меньше): *remake, makable*.